# VS2012 automated deployment - OutputPath property is not set for project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, build-definition

Ok, I know this has been asked a bunch of times...

I have tried to change the configuration and the outputPath, but still I have this issue.

I am setting up automated build and deployment for our product.
We have a single solution file and multiple projects within it.

Using VS2012 and the default build definition, I have set the "Items to build" to a single project - the one we wish to have build and deployment for.

Lets call this project "Forms".

When I run the build definition, it builds and says success. However, it gives a warning:

> $/XXX/TRUNK/XXX/Forms.Web/Forms.Web.csproj - 0 error(s), 1 warning(s),
>   View Log File 
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets
>   (610): The OutputPath property is not set for project
>   'Forms.Web.csproj'.  Please check to make sure that you have specified
>   a valid combination of Configuration and Platform for this project. 
>   Configuration='Release'  Platform='Any CPU'.  You may be seeing this
>   message because you are trying to build a project without a solution
>   file, and have specified a non-default Configuration or Platform that
>   doesn't exist for this project.

I have checked the .csproj file and there is a property group with the OutputPath specified.

I've also tried various combinations of configuration/platform, but the issue remains.

Does anyone have any idea what could cause this? It's driving me nuts. Without this fixed, no deployment is done... It seems to only build and doesn't even generate the .DLL files.

Comment: Is the OutputPath from the .csproj displayed in Visual Studio too?

Comment: If you mean like by going to properties > Build > Output then yes, it shows the output path as bin\Release\

Comment: Did you try running Visual Studio as admin?

Answer (score 0):

Try to **delete the "Platform" environment variable.**

(Visual Studio use this environment variable, which is possibly wrong.)

Then restart VS, and re-build the solution...

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?